# html div over background image

Tags: css, html

I have a template for a website, it's an image which i have set as a background image. Now what i need to do is place html over it. For example there an part of the whole template where some images are but eventually when they are clicked they need to do something. So i need to place some divs over the whole template containing the different parts.

I don't know what the right approach for this is. What i've done right now is set the background image like this:

```
#body{
    width:1280px;
    height:8000px;
    background: url(something.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:center;
}
```

So it always centers the image if you were to resize the window it would stay centered. This works fine.

Now i need to add another div in the body (of course) which needs to stay on top of the image.

I've tried and searched on the internet alot but the div seems to have a position that can't move. so how i resize the window it keeps in the same place.

I hope it's a little clear what i'm trying to do, and keep in mind this is my first time doing something like this so any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

PS: i'm not trying to cover the whole page in the background, just the original size which is 1280 all the time, and if the window gets resized bigger than 1280 in width it needs to center the image.

Comment: Most probably, you want a centered div. Use margin:auto and specify a width for the div, so it will be centered in the screen.

Comment: You can use `background-size:cover` for a full-page background-image http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Answer (score 0):

(if you're trying to set an image as the body's background to cover the whole screen)

Instead of settings width's and height's on your body, you should just set the size of the background to `cover`

css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image

```
body {
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
     -moz-background-size: cover;
       -o-background-size: cover;
          background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this so the image is always centered

```
.main{
    width:600px;
    margin:50px auto;
}


<div class="main">
  <img src="path to img"/>
</div>
```